# ReadableNativeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String when using Firestore and Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

[image: error message]

I was trying to write data to Firestore but got this error. The error only appeared after data had been written (about 1 min). I looked it up and it seems like firebase has a problem with expo-pixi. I am using lottie js and not sure if this is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the error is with Firebase. Since I was using the web SDK it tried to create an HTMLImageElement which will break when JS Engine try to convert it to android java component. The solution is to type `global.Image = undefined`.[More info here](https://github.com/expo/browser-polyfill/issues/35)